# How to send nested http requests with condition inside switchmap?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, observable

Hi I have a function and I want to send two http requests, the second request just if the first one is completed, I am using switchMap inside pipe with a condition based on one angular form and my editor shows the next error:

```
Argument of type '(data: Object) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.
```

This is my function:

```
  store() {
        this.empleadosEmpleadoService.store({
          fecha_contratacion:  this.empleadoForm.value.fecha_contratacion,
          fecha_nacimiento:  this.empleadoForm.value.fecha_nacimiento,
          curp: this.empleadoForm.value.curp,
          rfc: this.empleadoForm.value.rfc,
          telefono: this.empleadoForm.value.telefono,
          user: {
            email:  this.empleadoForm.value.email,
            username:  this.empleadoForm.value.username,
            password:  this.empleadoForm.value.password,
            first_name:  this.empleadoForm.value.first_name,
            last_name:  this.empleadoForm.value.last_name
          }
        }).pipe(
          switchMap(data =>{
    
            if(this.empleadoForm.value.foto){
              this.empleadosEmpleadoService.subirFoto(
                data['user_id'],
                this.empleadoForm.value.foto
                )
            }
         })
          ).subscribe(async empleado => {
    
          if(empleado) {
            this.empleadoForm.reset();
            this.empleadoAgregado.emit(empleado);
            this.dismissModal();
          }
        
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To a `switchMap`, you need to return an Observable, because you are switching from the source. Since source is an observable stream, the switched input should be an observable stream as well.

Assuming `this.empleadosEmpleadoService.subirFoto` is also a network request, it should return an observable, which you need to return to switchMap.

Notice the two `return` statements below:

```js
import { of as observableOf } from 'rxjs';
 
  store() {
        this.empleadosEmpleadoService.store({
          fecha_contratacion:  this.empleadoForm.value.fecha_contratacion,
          fecha_nacimiento:  this.empleadoForm.value.fecha_nacimiento,
          curp: this.empleadoForm.value.curp,
          rfc: this.empleadoForm.value.rfc,
          telefono: this.empleadoForm.value.telefono,
          user: {
            email:  this.empleadoForm.value.email,
            username:  this.empleadoForm.value.username,
            password:  this.empleadoForm.value.password,
            first_name:  this.empleadoForm.value.first_name,
            last_name:  this.empleadoForm.value.last_name
          }
        }).pipe(
          switchMap(data =>{
    
            if(this.empleadoForm.value.foto){
             // Assuming this.empleadosEmpleadoService.subirFoto returns an Observable
              return this.empleadosEmpleadoService.subirFoto(
                data['user_id'],
                this.empleadoForm.value.foto
                )
            }
            
            // You must return an observable to a switchMap
            return observableOf(data); // Or return whatever you want
         })
          ).subscribe(async empleado => {
    
          if(empleado) {
            this.empleadoForm.reset();
            this.empleadoAgregado.emit(empleado);
            this.dismissModal();
          }
        
        });
      }
```

```js
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.

// is complaining that you needed to return an Observable, but you are returning 'void' (not returning anything)
```

Comment: Yes two network requests now is working with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your switchMap a bit by adding `return` inside if and returning empty observable in else case

```
 switchMap(data =>{
    
            if(this.empleadoForm.value.foto){
              return this.empleadosEmpleadoService.subirFoto(
                data['user_id'],
                this.empleadoForm.value.foto
                )
            };
           return EMPTY
         })
```

Comment: I tried this but it is not working for this situation.